# How to look up multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel document that I am using to sign out hand held scanners to users in a department. I have set this up so that I can scan the employees ID into column A and then scan the bar code on the hand held scanner in column B. This automatically populates the date and time that the user was assigned the hand held scanner into column C and D.

When the user returns the scanner at the end of the day, we then scan the bar code of the scanner into column I and the date and time that it was returned are populated into Column E and F. This then shows that the user has returned the scanner.

The problem I am having is that if this hand held scanner is then signed out to a different person after being returned by the first person, the date and time in Column E and F are automatically populated from the date and time that the first employee returned the same scanner.

Is there a way to have column E and F populate the date and time that the scanner was returned based on the name of the employee that returned it? <strike>I can email the spreadsheet to anyone that would be able to help me so you can see exactly what I am talking about and the formulas I am currently using</strike>

Comment: Share you formula(s) in your question (specifically the ones you are having trouble with). DO NOT email it to anyone. Doing so defeats the purpose of Super User being community Q & A.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not to provide the direct answer you are looking for, but maybe it’s time to switch to a database.  It seems like soon you will reach the limitations of a single table (spreadsheet) and could benefit from something more robust.  Maybe an access application?  I have similar system, but mines tied to a database and some tech I made.  Hopefully you’ll find an answer to get you moving your problem while you contemplate my advice ;)